# In A TPacketDataSet->Data usModified record, How can I determine which fields carry NULL value because they were deliberately changed to NULL?

Tags: database, c++builder, datasnap, tclientdataset

I copy the `TClientDataSet->Delta` to `TPacketDataSet->Data`.
Then I am using `TPacketDataSet->Data` to write cached updates to Faircom Server ISAM database record. When using the Modified Record pair, The second copy of the record marked "usModified" holds every field, modified or not, with the unmodified fields carrying `NULL` as the `NewValue`.
 Question:  How can I determine which fields carry `NULL` value because they were deliberately changed to `NULL`, and which fields are `NULL` because they weren't changed? Simply writing `NewValue` to the persistence layer would result in clearing all field values which were not changed.

Comment: What about checking the field's [OldValue](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Data.DB.TField.OldValue)?

Comment: It really doesn't help.  If NewValue is NULL if not changed, and NULL if changed to NULL, comparing it to OldValue doesn't clarify the intention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use InitAltRecBuffers and see if NewValue is Unassigned (not changed) or Null (cleaned)

Comment: Are you able to provide an example?

Comment: Thank you vavan.  Testing NewValue for VarIsEmpty (Unassigned) was the solution.